# Iterate over a vector and create another vector based on elements

Tags: c++, vector

Maybe a stupid/naive question, but if I have a vector of vectors like this:

`std::vector<std::vector<Element> vec`

what is the most efficient way to create another vector from this one which containes all the sizes of elements from the previous vector:

`std::vector<std::size_t> newVector = {vec[0].size(), ..., vec[vec.size()-1].size()}`

is there a function for stuff like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a 1-liner approach using something from `<algorithm>` or fancy accumlator/transform routine.  But it's hard to beat the readability of this:

```
std::vector<std::size_t> newVector;
for (const auto& item : vec) {
    newVector.push_back(item.size());
}
```

If you prefer the hip way to do it, which some people like, but in my opinion makes for rather unreadable code.

```
vector<int> newVec(vec.size());
std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), newVec.begin(), [](vector<int>& v) {return v.size(); });
```

Comment: @aa - I took the opportunity to refamiliarize myself with std::transform and updated my answer. Fixed a typo too.  I still don't think std::transform makes for a better line of code for a case as simple as this.

Comment: Since you mentioned the "hip" way: `std::ranges::transform(vec, std::back_inserter(newVec), std::ranges::size);`, or even use the range adaptor: `vec | std::ranges::views::transform(std::ranges::size)`